# Toshiba Satellite c640 native display not recognized but screen doesn't seem to be dead

Tags: laptop, display

This is for a Toshiba c640 laptop.

My laptop only displays on external monitor.

Here is info about this problem:

- Display on laptop flickers on start up
- Display on laptop is not completely blank, it emits light
- Had this problem before months ago, and it resolved itself
- Laptop screen doesn't show up in multiple displays
- When pressing F5 , the laptop doesn't toggle between laptop and external monitor

I have tried to uninstall nvidia drivers, intel drivers, still the native display is not showing up in device manager,and not showing up on select display in diplay properties

[image]

Comment: The screen is most likely dead or disconnected.

Comment: Screen is lighting up, but dim, like when you boot a  PC and the little cursor is flashing on top left, if the lights are out in the room, the screen is lit,but dim, very dim, but nothing on it, so there is current going to the screen,additionally, it flickers when I boot before deciding to stay stuck on external monitor

Comment: Your comment adds nothing to what was already posted in the question (and if it did then it should have been [edit]ed in the question itself). Again, hardware issue. Please contact a repair service.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was defective hard disk, non related to screen, laptop had 2 disks, so that caused the confusion. I put the disks in a desktop, and got same behavior, conclusively, screen was fine.